# Replace file icon in search results not working for all file types (docicon.xml) (SP2010)

Tags: 2010

I've modified the docicon.xml file to replace some of the icons by custom icons, however not all the icons are replaced. I'm testing the icons using a search result page.
I've managed to replace e.g. the Word document icon but asp and htm files do not seem to get a custom icon. Also before modification of the docicon file, the icons refered to by the file are not used. SharePoint seems to load the html16.png file by default for most of the file types.

Can someone explain why it is loading the html16.png file instead of the configured icons, specified in the docicon.xml file?

Comment: how many servers are in your farm? Have you tried an iisreset and a sharepoint timer service reset?

Comment: I'm testing on a local development machine. I did run iisreset after each change. The starnge thing is, is that the default docicon.xml file tells SharePoint e.g. to use the file ichtm.gif for .htm, however SharePoint uses the html16.png icon for it.